# Ninject contextual bindings creating and resolution

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

1) Is it possible to retrieve bindings of specific context from kernel (made by `.Named("context")` method?

2) Is it possible to resolve bindings from multiple contexts simething like this `MyKernel.GetAll<MyType>(context1, context2)`?

3) Is it possible to force ninject kernel push all bindings into concrete context while using kernels `bind` methods without `.Named(string)`?

4) Is it possible to modify created bindings afterwards (for isntance call `.Named(string)` method upon them?

5) Is it possible to grab one bindings from one kernel and push it to another?

Answer (score 0):

All are impossible except for 4), where under some circumstances you can use `Rebind<IFoo>` to replace a previous `Bind<IFoo>`.